# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,) numpy related

Tags: keras, deep-learning, model, prediction, machine-translation

I am trying to predict the pretrained model of keras Machine translation

but i get the error and i could not solve or find suitable answer

and it seems everyone gets this ***error***

code**:**

```
model = load_model('model.h5')

single_x_test = ['how are you']

model.predict(np.array(single_x_test, ndmin=0))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to
>   have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: share more information about code.Because the error concerns the model.Share the model you use or on which tutorial or other to which you referred.

Comment: the model is seq2seq and with 3 layer LSTM and RNN

Comment: what exactly i have to share about my model?? model.summery

Comment: model.summery would help, apparently, to know at least your model input shape

Comment: please @alift see the update. this is my model summery is it enough or i should post the weights also

Comment: have you tried np.array([single_x_test])?

Comment: Model summary show you have an embedding layer at the beginning which accepts data of dimension (4,500). 

You should have a middle layer somewhere which translates the raw text to such dimension ( I. beleive that should be an embedding model or something like that)

Comment: model.predict(np.array([single_x_test]))    i tried this line as you said but still same error

Comment: @Zrufy it is not that the issue. Look at the model summary, the input is obviously not a raw text

Comment: it is working if i use test.txt in my main program and generate result.txt

Comment: but what i want it making the prediction for pre-trained model

Comment: the input is seems 2d array i think i am trying with 1d array i do not know how to solve this

Comment: @alift 
yes you're right I checked back now

Comment: so any idea i do not know what do to ?? it is like making the input none for th first 1D and then insert value to the second 1D

Comment: any solution?!?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you since this info is not enough.  When you mentioned "it is working if I use test.txt in my main program", what you mean? Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: yes i Updated see how does it make a test now can you find out what is exactly happening

Comment: OK! The magic happens in the function "load_test_data". You do not need to tell me what is inside, but feel free to go and have a look inside to see how it creates the X_test. You can wether use it in a way, or use its functionality to generate the input. Do not forget to apply pad_sequences function afterward as well before feeding it to the model

Comment: @alift yes you are right , i updated and you can see the function and can you help me how to predict with single sentences single input

Comment: I added an answer, feel free to accept it if it makes sense. good luck

Answer (score 1):

With the all the updates, I think if you change your code in this way, that might help to resolve your issue:

You need to change your load function a bit:

```
def load_test_data(X_data, X_word_to_ix, max_len):


    X = [text_to_word_sequence(x)[::-1] for x in X_data.split('\n') if 0 < len(x) <= max_len]
    for i, sentence in enumerate(X):
        for j, word in enumerate(sentence):

            if word in X_word_to_ix:
                X[i][j] = X_word_to_ix[word]
            elif word in X_word_to_ix is None:
                X[i][j] = None
            else:
                X[i][j] = X_word_to_ix['UNK']
    return X
```

And

```
model = load_model('model.h5')

single_x_test = 'how are you'

X=load_test_data(single_x_test, X_word_to_ix, max_len)
X= pad_sequences(X, maxlen=X_max_len, dtype='int32')
model.predict(X)
```

Hopefully this get you to what you want

Comment: hi thanks for answering but still got the same problem